# Why was Yaackov punished for answering Pharaoh's Question, "How old are you?"

Tags: reward-punishment, vayigash, jacob, pharaoh

Why was Yaackov punished for answering Pharaoh the way he did when pharaoh asked him how old he was?
I am sure Yaakov knew how to answer this easy to figure out question quite well. Well enough not to he punished by Gd to die over 30 years prematurely!

Comment: I assume you are referring to the medrash chadash cited by the daas zekanim, famously expounded upon in sichos mussar, by Rac Chaim Shmuelvitz. He asks why are Pharaoh's words also included in the calculation. He answers that Yaakov's perspective caused the question by making him look older due to his outlook. In that case, I don't know if any set of words were the issue, rather his outlook.

Comment: The gemara in sotah 5a is explicit that Yaakov was נאסף בזמנו, that he passed away in his proper time and not prematurely.